# Is it possible to update the SignInNames of already existing users in Azure AD using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-powershell-v2

Is it possible to update the AzureAD user's SignInNames using Powershell ?
I tried to update it but it doesn't work out and gives a Bad Request error. No specific error is given.
[image]

Let me know if that is possible!
Thanks!

Comment: Is the `creationType` of your b2c account is `LocalAccount`?

Comment: @JoyWang I am not sure what that property really means.
When the user was originally created, it didnt had any SignInNames property set. But now we want to set the SignInNames property of all the existing users. But I do see this error

Comment: @JoyWang Yes I have set the creationType prroperty to "LocalAccount" but it still doesn't work

Comment: My account `creationType` is null, I got an error said my account `creationType` is invaild, when I new a user via powershell, also got bad request.

Comment: According to the [AAD graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity), the `signInNames` could not be set after creating the account, may be it also could not be set via powershell, because if you catch the request of the powershell via fiddler, it essentially call the AAD graph api, too.

Comment: Woowww.. I love Microsoft :P

Comment: Do you think my comment is helpful? If so, I will add an answer.

Comment: Thanks @JoyWang :)

Comment: Have added an answer, may be you could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [AAD graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity), the `signInNames` could not be set after creating the account, may be it also could not be set via powershell, because if you catch the request of the powershell via fiddler, it essentially call the AAD graph api, too.